# ¿Cuál es la palabra más larga en español que no repite ninguna letra?

Tags: ortografía, curiosidades

[Ya sabemos que la más larga palabra en español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2079/what-is-the-longest-word-in-spanish) aceptada por la Real Academia Española es: [*Electroencefalografista*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=Electroencefalografista&m=form&o=h).

Pero, ¿cuál es la palabra más larga en español aceptada por la Real Academia Española que no repite ninguna letra? ¿Hay otras palabras no aceptadas oficialmente por la RAE?

Comment: Not a native speaker, but shouldn't that be "repita"?

Comment: @Michael I'm not a native speaker either. The indicative *repite* makes sense to me because it is a fact that there are words in Spanish that do not repeat letters (palabras que no repiten letras). I want to know which are the longest of those. But I could be wrong. Let's see whether a native speaker will clarify this matter. Otherwise you can post a question about it :)

Comment: good call. I asked here: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15899/se-debe-usar-el-indicativo-o-el-subjuntivo-en-esta-pregunta

Comment: @MichaelWolf By default I assume Spanish works as Portuguese. Got away with it this time :)

Comment: @Jacinto I don't know of any (simple?) case like this one in which Portuguese and Spanish differ in their choice of indicative versus subjunctive, but I may have missed some. Still, the linked questions seem to explain it well enough for both. A contrasting example that ***would*** use the subjunctive in both languages might be: *“(Me?) voy a quedarme quieto para ver si hay alguien que **sepa** la respuesta correcta”* and so *“Vou a ficar-me quieto para ver se há alguém que **saiba** a reposta correta”*. (And yes, that does seem to have a lot of *me* in it. :)

Comment: @tchrist, interesting, I know Portuguese and Spanish are very similar, of course, but I'm always a little weary. It is remarkable though that they should be so similar in the use of subjunctive/indicative, especially as the choice between the two has changed over time in Portuguse:modern dya  "talvez tenhas razão" vs. "talvez tens razão" still in use in the 19th century. See [this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/subjuntivo-ou-indicativo-depois-de-desde-que-e-talvez). Too much *me* indeed: "Vou ficar quieto"... in Portuguese, otherwise correct.

Comment: @Jacinto Certainly in Spanish the subjunctive *tal vez/talvez tengas* has become much more common than the indicative *t/v tienes* let alone of the rare "future of probability" *t/v tendrás* during the 20th century, whereas in the 19th century they were much more even. Perhaps more tellingly, the same pattern is found for *quizás/quizá*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parece que esta duda ha suscitado que diferentes personas crearan sus webs al respecto.

Cabría definir las reglas: ¿vale conjugar verbos? ¿sólo aceptamos las que recoja el Diccionario de la RAE?

Una búsqueda inicial me hace encontrar las siguientes en [Papel en blanco](http://www.papelenblanco.com/metacritica/algunas-curiosidades-muy-curiosas-de-la-lengua-espanola) y [Juegos de palabras](http://www.juegosdepalabras.com/longword.htm):

- Calumbrientos (13)
- Centrifugados (13)
- Vislumbrándote (14)

Estirando "centrifugados", nos encontramos con:

- Centrifugadlos (14)

Pero luego veo que en Juegos del ingenio ([copia caché](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XF3WVkhp4P0J:juegosdeingenio.org/archivo/640%20&cd=5&hl=es&ct=clnk&gl=us)) hay una larga discusión en la que salen:

- Hiperblanduzcos (15)

<s>Y finalmente el ganador:</s>

- Fluxygrandtezchimbos (20)

> Literalmente significa: Húmedos y grandes rostros de chimbos (pájaros
>   o bilbaínos).

<sub>Eliminado porque no hay referencias suficientemente fuertes de que exista esta palabra</sub>

Comment: Validando la existencia de la palabra Fluxygrandtezchimbos encontré 2 sitios web y un tweet de una cuenta en algún idioma del medio oriente donde claramente se han copiado uno del otro. Tres fuentes no muy creíbles que digamos. En la RAE esa palabra no aparece. Alguien puede citar una fuente seria?  No me gustaría que la respuesta aceptada tuviera información falsa.