# ¿Se debe usar el indicativo o el subjuntivo en esta pregunta?

Tags: subjuntivo, indicativa, tiempos-verbales

Hace unos meses, se hizo esta pregunta: *¿Cuál es la palabra más larga en español que no repite ninguna letra?*

En un comentario pregunté si sería mejor usar el subjuntivo —es decir, emplear *repita* en vez de *repite*— pero nadie que fuera hispanoparlante contestó.

Entonces, aquí repito la pregunta.

Comment: Por cierto, el título de esta pregunta es pésimo pero no se me ocurrió otro que fuera obviamente mejor.

Comment: Me expliqué mal en mi respuesta. Así que la borré.

Comment: Michael: how about «¿Cuál es la palabra más larga en español que no repite ninguna letra?» o «que no repita ...»? Or «Repite» o «repita» in «¿Cuál es la palabra más larga en español que no _______ ninguna letra?»

Answer (score 7):

En términos más técnicos, "que no repite ninguna letra" es una proposición subordinada adjetiva en función de complemento de "palabra" (en inglés, *a restrictive clause*). A partir de ello, pueden encontrarse muchas referencias online sobre el uso del subjuntivo en subordinadas adjetivas. En [este libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=Evbo6YFpX3cC&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=subjuntivo+en+complemento+de+nombre&source=bl&ots=Gtz6svBjKN&sig=NpBDxbn1B8jG-Md9aCEgIm3LWMA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX7LbnlNDKAhVE0RQKHbacBGMQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=subjuntivo%20en%20complemento%20de%20nombre&f=false) se explica que:

> "El indicativo representa al antecedente como algo o alguien existente y definido [...]. En el subjuntivo, el antecedente se representa como algo o alguien inexistente, dudoso o/e inconcreto"

Luego en tu ejemplo, si se quiere dar la idea de que el antecedente ("palabra") es una palabra concreta, se debe usar el indicativo. Ello tendría sentido pues se pide no una palabra cualquiera, sino "la más larga". Si en cambio se quiere expresar la idea de que la palabra podría ser cualquier palabra, esto es, algo indefinido, se deberá usar el subjuntivo. Ello también tiene sentido ya que, al momento de hacer la pregunta, la palabra aun se desconoce.

En resumen, ambas opciones son válidas, con una pequeña diferencia que no afecta al significado general de la pregunta. Como nativa, puedo asegurar que ambas suenan igual de correctas.

Para una mayor comprensión del uso del subjuntivo en subordinadas adjetivas, véase [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15178/subjuntivo-vs-indicativo-estaci%C3%B3n-que-me-sirve-sirva/15179#15179) (en [Subjuntivo vs Indicativo: "estación que me sirve/sirva](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15178/subjuntivo-vs-indicativo-estaci%C3%B3n-que-me-sirve-sirva?lq=1))

Comment: una nota:
> `Si en cambio se quiere expresar la idea de que la palabra podría ser cualquier palabra, esto es, algo indefinido, se deberá usar el subjuntivo`
"antecedente" es la primera parte .. con el verbo "ser".

Comment: @roberto no sé si te he entendido. El antecedente es "la palabra más larga en español", cuyo núcleo es "palabra". A lo mejor no es estrictamente correcto decir que el antecedente es solo "palabra", pero no vi necesario complicar la respuesta con sintagmas, núcleos, complementos de nombre, etc. Sea como sea, no veo cómo el verbo "ser" podría formar parte del antecedente.